# Subtracting current hour's value from previous hour's value in Power BI

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerquery, powerbi-desktop, m

Is there a DATEADD equivalent for hours?

The smallest interval for DATEADD is DAY, but I need it to be HOUR.

I have a running total number that grows once per hour, I need to make a measure that calculates the hourly consumption. The total dataset spans over many years, with 24 readings per day, every day.

For example for monthly calculations (on a different solution) I use

```
Monthly = SUM('Readings'[VALUE]) - CALCULATE(SUM('Readings'[VALUE]), DATEADD('Date'[Date], -1, MONTH))
```

I need a similar solution to calculate hourly consumption for each of the 24 hours.

Sample table 'Readings':
[View Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iajiN.png)

So I would need a measure that knows for example on 01/01/20 at hour 1 (01:00) the consumption was 5 (145-140) etc.

Comment: Are you trying to calculate `DURATION`?

Comment: No. I need to get hourly consumption, but the database only records the aggregate number so for example to get the consumption 1st feb 2020 1:00 I need to take the consumption for that hour and subtract the consumption of the previous hour from it.